# Как создать страницы для нужных языков после wp_insert_post()

Tags: wordpress, polylang

Ситуация такая...

Я добавляю пост через wp_insert_post(). После добавления поста, я получаю ID  поста. Нужно, чтобы в этот момент были добавлены и переводы для этого поста.

У меня плагин стоит polylang.
В инете искал решение для данной задачи, [вроде есть](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/programmatically-set-post-language-and-translations/), но оно не подходит, поскольку мне надо еще и получить ID переводов.

Мой код выглядит так.

```
$customfields = array(
    'name' => $name,
    'surname' => $surName,
    'email' => $email,
    'position' => $donorPosition,
    'phone' => $phone,
    'address' => $address,
    'currency' => $currencyType,
    'comment' => $notes,
    'paysystem' => $payMethod,
    'status' => 'pending',
    'projectid' => $projectId,
    'amount' => $amount,
    'anonymous' => $anonymous,
    'custom_amount' => $customAmount,
    'exchange' => $exchange
);

$postFields = array(
    'post_status'    => 'publish',         // Post status.
    'post_title'     => 'Donated by '.$name.' '.$surName, // Post title.
    'post_type'      => 'custompayments', // Post type.
    'meta_input'     => array( 'custompaymentsfields'=> $customfields )// Add meta fields
);
$post_id = wp_insert_post( $postFields);
```

Мне нужно, таким образом, сразу добавить и переводы.

Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы должны создать перевод так же, как и основной пост

```
$post_id_ru = wp_insert_post( $postFieldsRU);
```

И затем указать Polylang, что посты связаны:

```
$translations = [
    'en' => $post_id, 
    'ru' => $post_id_ru, 
] ;

pll_save_post_translations( $translations );
```