# Запрос на перевод/копирование поста через Wordpress CLI

Tags: php, wordpress, api, консоль

Есть вот такой запрос:

```
wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=product&from_post=52112&new_lang=uk&_wpnonce=89058730a2
```

он создает перевод товара в админке wordpress. Так вот, мне нужно каким то образом сделать такой запрос НЕ вручную через браузер, а программно посредством php кода, чтобы потом добавить его в свой скрипт загрузки товаров. Собственно интересует можно ли это каким то образом сделать посредством WP CLI или же используя какие то функции или классы самого wordpress, подключив их в своем скрипте?

Если говорить подробно то я пишу скрипт загрузки товаров при помощи Woocommerce API, однако перевод на сайте реализован посредством плагинов Loco Translate и Polylang, проблема в том что данные плагины совместимы с woocommerce в ручном режиме но не совместимы с woocommerce API. Поэтому ищу способ добавить переводы загруженных товаров не средствами woocommerce API, а например через API Wordpress или же другим способом, но не знаю как это сделать, так как в wordpress пока новичек и структуру движка знаю плохо.

Подскажите может кто сталкивался с подобными задачами?

Comment: Товары - это посты кастомного типа. Вот мой ответ по программному созданию переводов в Polylang: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1099413/220220

Answer (score 0):

Алексей, спасибо за подсказку, вопрос с переводом решил. Помогла документация плагина https://polylang.wordpress.com/documentation/documentation-for-developers/functions-reference/

В своем скрипте я сперва подключил функции wordpress:

```
require_once(__DIR__ . '/wp-load.php');
global $wpdb;
```

а затем использовал функции pll_save_post_translations() и pll_set_post_language()